# Training and Test Set in Weka InCompatible in Text Classification

Tags: weka, random-forest, text-classification

I have two datasets regarding whether a sentence contains a mention of a drug adverse event or not, both the training and test set have only two fields the text and the labels{Adverse Event, No Adverse Event} I have used weka with the stringtoWordVector filter to build a model using Random Forest on the training set.

I want to test the model built with removing the class labels from the test data set, applying the StringToWordVector filter on it and testing the model with it. When I try to do that it gives me the error saying training and test set not compatible probably because the filter identifies a different set of attributes for the test dataset. How do I fix this and output the predictions for the test set.

Comment: Your question is missing data, it would be beneficial to provide sample data and the exact **error**

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this for a one off test is not to pre-filter the training set, but to use Weka's [FilteredClassifier](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/meta/FilteredClassifier.html) and configure it with the StringToWordVector filter, and your chosen classifier to do the classification. This is explained well in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tggs3Bd3ojQ&list=PLm4W7_iX_v4OMSgc8xowC2h70s-unJKCp&index=11) from the More Data Mining with Weka online course.

For a more general solution, if you want to build the model once then evaluate it on different test sets in future, you need to use [InputMappedClassifier](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/index.html?weka/classifiers/misc/InputMappedClassifier.html):

> Wrapper classifier that addresses incompatible training and test data
>   by building a mapping between the training data that a classifier has
>   been built with and the incoming test instances' structure. Model
>   attributes that are not found in the incoming instances receive
>   missing values, so do incoming nominal attribute values that the
>   classifier has not seen before. A new classifier can be trained or an
>   existing one loaded from a file.

Answer (score 0):

Weka requires a label even for the test data. It uses the labels or „ground truth“ of the test data to compare the result of the model against it and measure the model performance. How would you tell whether a model is performing well, if you don‘t know whether its predictions are right or wrong. Thus, the test data needs to have the very same structure as the training data in WEKA, including the labels. No worries, the labels are not used to help the model with its predictions.

The best way to go is to select cross validation (e.g. 10 fold cross validation) which automatically will split your data into 10 parts, using 9 for training and the remaining 1 for testing. This procedure is repeated 10 times so that each of the 10 parts has once been used as test data. The final performance verdict will be an average of all 10 rounds. Cross validation gives you a quite realistic estimate of the model performance on new, unseen data.

What you were trying to do, namely using the exact same data for training and testing is a bad idea, because the measured performance you end up with is way too optimistic. This means, you‘ll get very impressive figures like 98% accuracy during testing - but as soon as you use the model against new unseen data your accuracy might drop to a much worse level.